# Search based on Properties

Tags: c#

I have an Employee table ,let us assume with Columns-- Name, Age,Dept.

I need to do search based on condition like

1. FIRST: exact match on Name,Age, Dept
2. SECOND: exact match + exact match  (exact Match on any two)
3. THIRD: exact match

   If First Match is found , then well and good.If no Match then we need to go for Second Option where we need to find result if there is any match between two parameters.

Note: I am looking for a Generic Solution(Imagine I have properties to search)

Example: EMP table

[image]

If User is searching "A" ,21 and "CSC" then it is straight forward, I can write the code like

```
context.Emp.Any(p => p.Name== "A"&& p.Age== 21&& p.Dept== "csc");
```

If user is Searching like "B" "19
" and "DDD" then i can ignore Dept DDD  and return Second row , as there is no Exact Match, then i searching with only two properties Match

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and we're you're stuck ! You can probably solve this with a few `OR` conditions

Comment: Have you looked at LINQ ?

Comment: yes, I looked in Linq, but how can I make a generic search. I what I am thinking about

Comment: I downvoted because I see no effort about trying to solve the problem yourself nor any hint where you have issues with your current solution. Also no code to reproduce what you are trying. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *but how can I make a generic search* → What's your expectation by generic? Please explain the inputs and expected output and share some example. The question in the current format is unclear.

Comment: With your edits it's easier to understand the issue, so I removed my downvote and added an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate a score based on the number of matches, order by the score and take the first result. Something like this should work:

```
var bestMatch = context.Emp.Select(
new {
    Score = (c.Age == age ? 1 : 0) + (c.Dept == dept ? 1 : 0) + (c.Name == name ? 1 : 0),
    Emp = c
}).OrderByDescending(c => c.Score).FirstOrDefault()?.Emp;
```

P.S.: You also can order directly by the formula without selecting it into an anonymous object first, but I like the readability of the above approach.